# Как узнать откуда вызывается метод?

Tags: android, классы, методы

Есть класс, который может вызываться из 4х мест. В классе есть лисенер (лисенер переопределяемый из андроидных библиотек - его параметры не поменять). Необходимо заставлять этот лисенер работать по разному в зависимости от того, кто его вызывает.
Как можно этого добиться?

```
Visualizer.setDataCaptureListener(bla, bla,bla)

public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] fft, int samplingRate) {}
```

Comment: Изивните, а можно более точно указывать классы? Какой именно Listener? OnClick... или OnChangeChecked...? Их там довольно много.

Comment: спасибо, я думал об этом, но решил спросить, вдруг есть другой способ,а то я могу что-нибудь кривое выдать.

Answer (score 1):

А откуда берутся `Visualizer`? если создаются тобой, то можно переопределить класс, добавить туда поле с тегом. В лисенере кастовать `Visualizer` из параметров в свой класс и получать тег.